# AngularJS PouchDB change-listener

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, pouchdb

I followed some tutorials on the web for todo lists... but I think, these tutorials don't use best practises for the implementation. All code is in the controller.
My controller looks like this and I think the code for the change-listener is not at the best "place" there. Where should I implement the listener?

```
.controller('TodosCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'Todo', function($scope, $state, Todo) {
  $scope.create = function() { $state.go('todo_create'); };
  $scope.todos= [];
  $scope.$on('$ionicView.loaded', function() {
    localDB.changes({ 
      since: 'now',
      live: true,
      include_docs: true
    }).on('change', function (change) {
      if (change.doc && change.doc._id.substring(0, change.doc._id.indexOf('_')) === 'todo') {
        if (change.deleted) {
            ....
        } else {
            ....
        }
      }
    });
  });


  Todo.all().then(function (result) { 
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      $scope.todos.push(result[i].doc);
    }
  });


}])
```

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually all related code the is coupled to the DOM should be in the controller.
All other logic should be inserted to services.

See my comment for an exmaple:

```
.controller('TodosCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'Todo', function($scope, $state, Todo) {
        $scope.create = function() { $state.go('todo_create'); };
        $scope.todos= [];
        $scope.$on('$ionicView.loaded', function() {
            localDB
                /** Not sure exactly what it is but if that some sort of initialization - this is better to be placed in one of the services 
                .changes
                ({
                    since: 'now',
                    live: true,
                    include_docs: true
                })
                */
                .on('change', function (change) {
                    if (change.doc && change.doc._id.substring(0, change.doc._id.indexOf('_')) === 'todo') {
                        if (change.deleted) {
                        ....
                        } else {
                        ....
                        }
                    }
                });
        });


        Todo.all().then(function (result) {
            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                $scope.todos.push(result[i].doc);
            }
        });
    }]) ;
```

Comment: But I use the $scope variable in the listener... so the code is related to the dom, is that correct?

Comment: How can I put the listener in a service, if the $scope is needed?

Comment: The $scope is specific for each controller and cannot be related inside a service.
This means that indeed you cannot put the listener in a service.
What you can put in a listener is the initialization like I mention in my code (and other non-DOM dependent stuff)